# initWithContentsOfURL seems to have issues with "long" URLs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm facing a rather strange Issue when trying to load data from an XML-Webservice.
The webservice allows me to pass separated identifiers within the URL-Request. 
It is therefore possible for the URL to become rather long (>240 characters). 
If I open said URL in firefox the response arrives as planned, if I execute the following code `xmlData` remains empty.

```
NSString *baseUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[kSearchDateTimeRequestTV stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{LANG}" withString:appLanguageCode] 
                                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{IDENTIFIERS}" withString:myIdentifiers]
                                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{STARTTICKS}" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[startTime getTicks] descriptionWithLocale:nil]]]
                                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{ENDTICKS}" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[endTime getTicks] descriptionWithLocale:nil]]]];

NSLog(baseUrl); //looks good, if openend in browser, returnvalue is ok

urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl];


NSString *xmlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]; //err is nil, therefore i guess everything must be ok... :(

NSLog(xmlData); //nothing...
```

is there any sort of URL-Length restriction, does the same problem happened to anyone of you as well? whats a good workaround?

thanks for your help

sam

Comment: I narrowed it down a bit to the fact that after urlRequest = [NSURL UrlWithString:baseUrl] , the NSLog([urlRequest absoluteURL]); doesn't show anything on the console.. so it's definitively an issue with UrlWithString limiting the length of an URL... at least that's my guess....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before passing baseURL to URLWithString you must ensure that it is a valid url otherwise it will return NULL.
You can use the following line of code to encode non-valid characters to percent-escape sequence:

```
NSString *fixedURL = [baseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // or any other encoding
```

Most browsers will actually do this automatically for you if you pass invalid characters in the URL, so this might be the reason the url works in Firefox.

Claus

Comment: that, unfortunately, doesn't solve my problem. I really think the issue here is the length of my URL, because if myIdentifiers (which looks somthing like this: "234|2348|3923|2398" is short enough, the whole request works. 
thanks for your help anyway..

Comment: Those vertical lines in your identifier are not valid characters in an url

Comment: oh well, seems like I have to say sorry :) you were right, I was wrong and I also looked at the wrong part of my code :(.. thanks again!